# How to delete specific file with command prompt/batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have 2 files in the same folder.
These file names are
**test.xlsx**
and
**test.xlsx.jhdrsx**

I want to delete the second file. (test.xlsx.jhdrsx)

I should say, If file extension length is 6 character then "delete the file"
or
If there is 6 character till ".", then delete

I have 60k file like that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly in Windows there is no file pattern that works in this case.
But you can try some scripting like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /b ^| findstr /r "/c:\.[^\.\\][^\.\\][^\.\\][^\.\\][^\.\\][^\.\\]$"') do del "%~d"
```

This lists the files in the current directory and filters them by: extension has exactly six characters.
The pattern is:

- one point
- six times any character other than point or backslash
- end of line

Comment: Actually, I should say ,
If file extension length is 6 character "delete it"

Comment: I dont understand how to works?
I've made a bat file with this code.
But didnt work.
how I'll do that?

Comment: If you are in a Batch file you have to replace the % by %%.

Comment: it's work only for same folder.
How to make for all disk ( c:\ or D:\ )

Comment: dear @Konrad ;
how to delete from all disk ?

Comment: No need to exclude `\ `by `findstr` from file names as long as you do not use `/S` option of `dir`...

Comment: @Byzt: Sorry for the very late answer. For the whole disk you should use **/s** option for the **dir** command.  <br/>And keep the \ to be excluded by findstr.    For your security you could use the **/p** option for the **del** command, so you are requested to confirm the deletion for each file.

Answer (score 0):

for every file (`*`) check if extension (`%%~xa`) sixth character is not empty and seventh character is empty (-> extension is exactly six chars long) then delete the file.
`/R` makes it recursive (search through subfolders), `"C:\"` defines the startfolder.

```
 @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /R "C:\" %%a in (*) do (
  set ext=%%~xa
  if "!ext:~7,1!" equ "" if "!ext:~6,1!" neq "" ECHO del "%%a"
)
```

Note: this code just outputs the delete commands to the screen. If you are satisfied, remove the `ECHO`

Comment: When I removed the ECHO paramater, its give me an error.
"System does not find path"

Comment: probably you have spaces in (some of) the path/file names. Put quotes around `%%a` (edited in my answer)